# Search MySQL database where fields contain symbols

Tags: php, mysql

I have a location database on my MySQL server containing UK postcodes, postal towns, counties and coordinates. If one were to search for "connahs" (real result is "Connah's Quay"), no results would be returned because they did not include the apostrophe. The same applies to hyphens and other symbols.

In this example, the postal town "Connah's Quay" is the correct format, so I can't just remove the symbol from the database.

My query so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes WHERE postal_town LIKE "connahs%" ORDER BY postal_town LIMIT 25
```

Is there any way I can search for fields both containing symbols (connah's) and not (connahs) so that regardless of whether the user uses the apostrophe it returns results?

Comment: LIKE wildcards can match any number of characters, including 0.  `connah%s%` would match `connahs` and `connah's` but it would also match anything that began with `connah` followed by any number of characters followed by an `s`, so it may not be an ideal solution.  It might be better to add multiple LIKE statements with OR

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql replace function. Query will be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes WHERE  REPLACE( postal_town, "'", "" )   
LIKE "connahs%" ORDER BY postal_town LIMIT 25
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Using MYSQL REPLACE inline slows the search down to a crawl. There are over 1.7M results to filter, so replacing each result and attempting a match is not a suitable fix.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you are using php in your code.

```
// get the value of searched word from searchbox or something...
$keyword = $_POST['uk_postcodes'];
// avoid sql injection to, also read for special characters
$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($keyword);
$keyword = stripslashes($keyword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM uk_postcodes WHERE postal_town LIKE %$keyword ORDER BY postal_town LIMIT 25";
```

In the code above, you can type anything!

Comment: Not what the OP was asking, and use of obsolete mysql_* functions.